# DisplayLink USB monitor with Ubuntu 14.04 and nVidia GPU

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, 64-bit, nouveau, displaylink

I figured even before reading http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition that DisplayLink won't work with proprietary nVidia driver. I also see that the USB monitor (and AOC) is activated while the machine is booting. As soon as the proprietary driver kicks in, it blanks out.

If I enable nouveau driver and reboot the machine, only the USB monitor shows the graphical display, and my notebook's monitor remains blank. When I look into Unity's standard "Displays" settings, only the AOC monitor is detected. (When I run proprietary nVidia driver, only the Built-in Display is detected). The color depth is very low though, but I wouldn't mind that too much as a secondary monitor. I know it's not for gaming or video.

Could anyone help with this?
I'm running latest stock kernel of 64bit ubuntu: uname -a:
Linux erebus 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:06:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I can provide any other logs if needed, but I don't want to unnecessary clutter this post in advance. I hope someone else already got it working with this combination: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, nVidia GPU and DisplayLink monitor.

Comment: Extra information: I have an SLI config, so two graphics cards. Is nvidia-prime take part in any way when a DisplayLink monitor is used? Can the SLI config an extra situation in my case which is a problem?

Comment: Now DisplayLink provides an Ubuntu kernel driver. I haven't had luck with it yet. http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: Lately I used Ubuntu Studio (Xfce4) 15.04 and then 15.10. I bought a GeChic On-Lap a while ago. Very pricey, but has HDMI input.

Comment: Also states here http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/641668-known-issues-with-displaylink-ubuntu-support that closed source nvidia drivers are not supported

Comment: i would suggest unplugging the sli for now to remove complexity , then when you have linux setup with a single card renable it. I would recommend completely removing the second card not just unplugging the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what kind of DisplayLink monitor you have. In my case an AOC e2251fw, and it turned out that it uses DL-165 chipset, and for DL-1xx chips you won't need the EVGI driver + new DisplayLink driver. You can use the `udl` kernel driver and it even works along with the proprietary nvidia drivers.

See more: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink
and http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?p=81545#post81545

Still have some issues though: 
[Giant virtual monitor with DispayLink monitor + Xfce with additional annoying scroll effect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836574/giant-virtual-monitor-with-dispaylink-monitor-xfce-with-additional-annoying-sc)

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work on my Laptop with Intel Graphics + Nvidia 870M by switching the GPU from Nvidia to Intel using Nvidia X Server Settings. I'm using the Nvidia proprietary driver 352.xx and the latest displaylink linux drivers from displaylink's website.

Comment: I'd even go that way, but my laptop (Clevo P570WM) has desktop CPU in it and the i7-4820K doesn't have integrated graphics :(. Your solution seems like working for some people though. I''l give another try to the DisplayLink Linux driver if I have time...

Comment: Unfortunately it tells me I have to log out to apply the changes, which makes it of little use for me (may as well just not use nvidia).

Comment: My newest laptop has mobile CPU in it but there's no BIOS switch to enable the integrated graphics. I haven't tried any optimus switcher either.

Answer (score 0):

My display-link on Ubuntu 16.04 only worked with nouveau and Unity (not xfce, gnome etc).
With nvidia driver I couldn't even see the external displays/